# How to get AWS Lambda ARN using Terraform?

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform

I am trying to define a terraform output block that returns the ARN of a Lambda function. The Lambda is defined in a sub-module. According to the documentation it seems like the lambda should just have an ARN attribute already: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/lambda_function#arn

Using that as a source I thought I should be able to do the following:

```
output "lambda_arn" {
  value = module.aws_lambda_function.arn
}
```

This generates the following error:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on main.tf line 19, in output "lambda_arn":
  19:   value = module.aws_lambda_function.arn

This object does not have an attribute named "arn".
```

I would appreciate any input, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Documentation is correct. Data source `data.aws_lambda_function` has `arn` attribute. However, you are trying to access the `arn` from a custom module `module.aws_lambda_function`. To do this you have to define output `arn` in your module.

So in your module you should have something like this:

```
data "aws_lambda_function" "existing" {
  function_name = "function-to-get"
}

output "arn" {
  value = data.aws_lambda_function.existing.arn
}
```

Then if you have your module called `aws_lambda_function`:

```
module "aws_lambda_function" {
   source = "path-to-module"   
}
```

you will be able to access the `arn`:

```
module.aws_lambda_function.arn
```

Comment: I just realized that I have defined my lambda as a resource instead of data. When I changed it to data I have access to the ARN but I cannot specify the filename for the lambda zip. Your answer resolved the original issue but can you provide any information on how to work around this?

Comment: @Michael Data source `data` only gets info about existing function. To create new one and specify its zip you have to use resource [aws_lambda_function](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function). You can't use `data` to modify existing function, only to get its information.

Comment: I was able to figure that out but it seems like it isn't possible to do what I am wanting. I want to create the function and give the user the ability to run `terrarform output` to see the function ARN. That doesn't seem possible though as it can't be part of the terraform code that generates it. Have I missed something?

Comment: @Michael Not sure what do you mean? You could make new question with new code examples and description of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have created a follow up question if you would be interested in taking a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65812853/how-to-structure-terraform-code-to-get-lambda-arn-after-creation