# How to structure terraform code to get Lambda ARN after creation?

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform

This was a previous question I asked: [How to get AWS Lambda ARN using Terraform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65798783/how-to-get-aws-lambda-arn-using-terraform)

This question was answered but turns out didn't actually solve my problem so this is a follow up.

The terraform code I have written provisions a Lambda function:

Root module:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
   region = var.region
   profile = var.aws_profile
}

module "aws_lambda_function" {
   source = "./modules/lambda_function"
}
```

Child module:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
   function_name = "lambda_function"
   handler = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
   runtime = "python3.8"
   filename = "./task/dist/package.zip"
   role = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_exec" {
   name = "aws_iam_lambda"
   assume_role_policy = file("policy.json")
}
```

What I want the user to be able to do to get the Lambda ARN:

```
terraform output
```

The problem: I cannot seem to include the following code anywhere in my terraform code as it causes a "ResourceNotFOundException: Function not found..." error.

```
data "aws_lambda_function" "existing" {
  function_name = "lambda_function"
}

output "arn" {
  value = data.aws_lambda_function.existing.arn
}
```

Where or how do I need to include this to be able to get the ARN or is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't lookup the `data` for a resource you are creating at the same time. You need to output the ARN from the module, and then output it again from the main terraform template.

In your Lambda module:

```
output "arn" {
  value = aws_lambda_function.lambda_function.arn
}
```

Then in your main file:

```
output "arn" {
  value = module.aws_lambda_function.arn
}
```